# Moving to next textbox when 5 entries are accepted

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to move to the next text box when a user has entered 5 scores. for example I give the following scores to the program; 100, 200, 300, 250, 150. Now I want it to move to the next text box so I can do it all over again. Currently I have a counter set up to count the number of accepted scores, I just need the line of code that will switch to the next text box.

```
ScoreArray(4)
counter=counter+1

if counter > 5 Then
'Move to next text box
else 
keep going
```

Comment: A text box is generally used for input. Are you wanting focus to be switched to the text box, or are you wanting the text box to be updated in some way?

Comment: I want the next text box to be focused so that as I continue to input they go into the next box. I know I need an array to do this I'm just not sure how to go about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to do something like this

```
for i=0 to ScoreArray.Length -1  Then
    'keep going
Next i 
    'Move to next text box
```

Comment: cant use If/Else unfortunatley

Comment: Why can't you use if/else?

Comment: Professor pretty much demanded it, pointless for a program this size but I think it's more of a lesson for the future should we be working in a program with thousands of repetitions

Comment: I have changed my answer

Comment: You might want to look at some loop tutorials.